# Pac Man cross obstacles

Tags: c#

I'm doing a Pac-Man game on c# , and pac man cross every obstacles that I pass.

This is the entire code of my Pac-Man game:

```
using System; 
using System.Media; 
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pac_Man {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
```

Variables:

```
bool goLeft;
        bool goRight;
        bool goUp;
        bool goDown;

        int score = 0;
        int totalCoins = 160;
        int playerSpeed = 4;

        int ghost1 = 4;
        int ghost2 = 4;
```

Initializing:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblGame.Visible = false;
            playSound();
        }
```

Play sound:

```
        private void playSound()
        {
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\rsss-\OneDrive\Documentos\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\Pac_Man\Pac_Man\Sound\pacman_beginning.wav");
            simpleSound.PlayLooping();
        }
```

Key is down:

```
        private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                goUp = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                goDown = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                goLeft = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                goRight = true;
            }
        }
```

Key is up:

```
        private void keyisup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                goUp = false;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                goDown = false;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                goLeft = false;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                goRight = false;
            }
        }
```

Timer:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int movement = playerSpeed;
            if (goLeft)
            {
                foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "obstacle" && x.Left == player.Left - playerSpeed && x.Top == player.Top)
                    {
                        movement = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                player.Left -= movement;
                movement = playerSpeed;
            }
            else if (goRight)
            {
                foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "obstacle" && x.Left == player.Left + playerSpeed && x.Top == player.Top)
                    {
                        movement = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                player.Left += movement;
                movement = playerSpeed;
            }
            else if (goUp)
            {
                foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "obstacle" && x.Top == player.Top - playerSpeed && x.Left == player.Left)
                    {
                        movement = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                player.Top -= movement;
                movement = playerSpeed;
            }
            else if (goDown)
            {
                foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "obstacle" && x.Top == player.Top + playerSpeed && x.Left== player.Left)
                    {
                        movement = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                player.Top += movement;
                movement = playerSpeed;
            }

            if (player.Left > 641)
            {
                player.Left = 82;
            }
            else if (player.Left < 82)
            {
                player.Left = 641;
            }

            foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "ghost")
                {
                    if (((PictureBox)x).Bounds.IntersectsWith(player.Bounds))
                    {
                        gameOver();
                        MessageBox.Show("You Lost!" + "\n" + "Your score is " + score);
                        this.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Ghosts Movement:

```
            redGhost.Left += ghost1;
            orangeGhost.Left += ghost2;
            blueGhost.Left -= ghost1;
            pinkGhost.Left -= ghost2;

            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c is PictureBox && c.Tag == "coin")
                {
                    if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(c.Bounds))
                    {
                        this.Controls.Remove(c);
                        score++;
                    }
                }
            }

            lblScore.Text = "Score: " + score;
            if (score == totalCoins)
            {
                gameOver();
                MessageBox.Show("You Win!" + "\n" + "You reach the maximum score: " + score);
                this.Close();
            }

        }
```

Game Over:

```
        private void gameOver()
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            lblGame.Visible = true;
            lblGame.Text = "Game Over!";
        }
    } }
```

Basically, I want that the character don't move in that direction if he hits an obstacle.
Anyone can help me?
Thank you.

Comment: try changing the condition `x.Left == player.Left - 5` to `x.Left <= player.Left - 5` ( or >=)

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what problem you're having? What do you want the code to do, and how does what you have not already do that?

Comment: i'm doing a pac-man game and the character is passing through all obstacles. i want that he don't do it

Comment: You are checking for collisions but you aren't actually doing anything with that information. You just check if its true, and if it is you break the loop. The simplest fix would probably be to set `playerSpeed = 0` right before your `break` statement but its tough to say for sure without seeing more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a different and hopefully simpler way to test for obstacle hit, I dont know if it can compile but i hope you get the general idea

First calculate x and y movement, then apply that movement to a copy of the players bounds and check if it intersects with any obstacle, if it does break out of the loop, if not test next obstacle
If no intersections found then move the player

Need to ensure that System.Drawing.Rectangle originalBounds = player.Bounds actually creates a copy of the players bounds, otherwise the player will move back and forward while the loop is running

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int moveX = 0;
     int moveY = 0;
     bool hitObstacle = false;
     System.Drawing.Rectangle originalBounds = player.Bounds; // make sure this is a copy of players bounds rectangle. 


     if(goLeft)     
        moveX = -playerSpeed;
     else if(goRight)     
        moveX = playerSpeed;
     else if (goUp)
        moveY = -playerSpeed;
     else if (goDown)
         moveY = playerSpeed;

     originalBounds.Offset(moveX,moveY);

     foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
     {
        if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "obstacle") {

            if (originalBounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds)) {
                hitObstacle = true;
                break;
            }
         }     
         if(hitObstacle==false) {
            player.Bounds=originalBounds;
          }

         if (player.Left > 641)
         .....
```

Comment: What exactly did you try (boolean flag or movement value?), and what do you mean by stuck on movements? Maybe you just need to reset obstacleFound to false or movement to playerSpeed - just edited the answer to clarify

Comment: i tried both. i just can move the character in a very limited space

Comment: That kind of indicates you are hitting an obstacle, are you sure you handle creation of the obstacles correctly ? And why -5 is that the default movement amount ? Shouldn't it be playerSpeed ?

Comment: You only test for one dimension, which means you will get a hit if *any* obstacles have the same x value, you need to add a test for y values as well, maybe something like `x.Top==player.Top` as i added to the answer

Comment: I added what you say to my code (as you can see on my edited answer) and I stil cross the obstacles. I can already move the character all over the space

Comment: Hmm, you must determine the correct check for y axis yourself, i just guessed on top.X 
I dont think i can help you much more then unless your code is available on github or somewhere else where i can see all of it , i think my answer answered your first question, so feel free to accept it

Comment: If i can see all of your code i would gladly take a look at it, otherwise best of luck :)

Comment: you can see all the code on the edited answer I made now. Thanks for the help

Comment: I just rewrote the answer, it uses a simpler approach (i hope)

Comment: i try what you indicated but i'm having the following errors: CS0200 Property or indexer 'Rectangle.Left' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only; CS0200; Property or indexer 'Rectangle.Top' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only;
CS1061 'Rectangle' does not contain a definition for 'Bounds' and no accessible extension method 'Bounds' accepting a first argument of type 'Rectangle' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: There was an error in the first version of the answer, originalBounds.Bounds.IntersectsWith should be originalBounds.IntersectsWith , i've fixed that. As well as the other issue Left+= and top+= is changed to offset instead